# Pass a boolean with a specific id

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Is it possible to pass a boolean with a specific `id` to the query parameter?

**The component for toggle is used.**

```
<v-toggle-button :defaultState='false' id='in_stock' ref='toggleAvailable'/>
```

**toggle-component**

```
<template>
 <label :for='id + "_button"' :class='{"active": isActive}' class='toggle__button'>
  <input type='checkbox' :id='id + "_button"' v-model='checkedValue'>
  <span class='toggle__switch'></span>
 </label>
</template>
```

**script toggle-component**

```
computed: {
  isActive() {
    return this.currentState;
  },
  checkedValue: {
    get() {
      return this.defaultState;
    },
    set(newValue) {
      this.currentState = newValue;
      this.$emit('change', newValue);
    }
  }
},
```

in one request I need to give `true` / `false` with `id: in_stock`, in another `id: under_order`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, can you elaborate?

Comment: @maxshuty 
There is a toggle button component, I connect it in the parent. In the parent, I send a request to the server. I have 2 requests, I need the first request to send a boolean from the first button, in the second request - from the second. (and this logic in the rest of the requests)

Comment: have you tryed emit a object?
something like: this.$emit('change', { newValue, id: this.id})